# More elegant way of creating button e.g. using single HTML element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out if there is a more elegant way of creating the following HTML button.

[image]

I'm currently creating it using an `<a href="...">` and 2 child `<span>` elements as follows: -

```
<a href="">
    <span class="box_button">Read more</span>
    <span class="box_button_arrow">&gt;</span>
</a>
```

The CSS looks like the following: -

```
span.box_button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 10px 8px 10px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
}
span.box_button_arrow {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 10px 8px 10px;  
  border-top: 4px solid white;
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
}
```

Notice how the arrow span doesn't have a border to it's left.

Here is the code pen - http://codepen.io/bobmarksie/pen/bEPVgM

Is it possible to replace the 2 span's with a single HTML element?

Comment: What is the problem with the way it's done right now?

Comment: The problem isn't that it doesn't work but rather in its elegance I.e. it requires 2 elements to create what is in essence a single HTML button! Having a single button IMO then makes the code more elegant / easier to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::after` to do this. With this solution you can remove the `span` elements. Here your updated example:

```css
div.info_box {
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #A95563;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
} 
div.box_title {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
div.box_main {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
  height: 120px;
}
a.box_button {
  border:4px solid #fff;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline;
  padding:6px 10px 8px 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.box_button::after {
  border-left:4px solid #fff;
  content:">";
  margin-left:10px;
  padding:6px 0px 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info_box">
  <div class="box_title">My title</div>
  <div class="box_main">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
  <a class="box_button" href="">Read more</a>
</div>
```

A working codepen you can find here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGQYyG

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Any tips on good resources for learning this more advanced CSS / HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Let's make the button a button semantically and style it with CSS. Here's the crux of the HTML, which is about as simple as it can get:

```
    <button class="button">
      Read more
    </button>
```

The CSS is where the heavy lifting is done. If you run the code snippet, it's very tough to spot the difference between this and the original.

```
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  button.button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 4px solid white;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 7px 46px 7px 10px;
    position: relative;
  }

  button.button:after {
    border-left: 4px solid white;
    content: ">";
    padding: 7px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0
  }
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.info_box {
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #A95563;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
} 
div.box_title {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
div.box_main {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
  height: 120px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button.button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 7px 46px 7px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

button.button:after {
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  content: ">";
  padding: 7px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="info_box">
  <div class="box_title">My title</div>
  <div class="box_main">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
  <a href="">
    <button class="button">
      Read more
    </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using :after selector

```
 <a href="">
    Read more
 </a>

a:after {
  content: ">";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inner spans, use `line-height` to center text vertically, and make use of the `::after` pseudo element, thus you'll have one element instead of 3

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/rxEOpB?editors=1100)

```css
div.info_box {
  float: left; width: 230px; height: 230px; padding: 40px; background: #A95563;
  color: white; font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
div.box_title { font-size: 22px; padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px; }
div.box_main { font-size: 16px; line-height: 120%; height: 120px; }

.box_button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box_button::after {
  content: '>';
  /* same value as .box_button padding-left, to have equal space on both sides */
  margin-left: 10px; 
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 4px white solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="info_box">
  <div class="box_title">My title</div>
  <div class="box_main">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
  <a href="" class="box_button">
  Read more
 </a>
</div>
```